# if f is a measurable function and $A$ a null set, is $f(A)$ a null set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

i've proven that for countable $A$ this is absolutely true, but i don't think this statement is true for uncountable A. I've tried to make a function with the cantor set but i still haven't found a real good counterexample.

help would be appreciated!

Kees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not even true for continuous functions.  Try the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: yeah, i already thought of that. I thought the cantor set construction wasn't a function but thanks this really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The result is certainly true for [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) functions and [diffeomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism). The classical counter-example is the Cantor function, as already pointed by Robert Israel.